# Jenkins controller node looks for known_hosts in /tmp/.ssh not JENKINS_HOME

Tags: jenkins

I set the Jenkins controller node to connect to an agent node using SSH. The problem is I get a message

```
/tmp/.ssh/known_hosts [SSH] No Known Hosts file was found at /tmp/.ssh/known_hosts. Please ensure one is created at this path and that Jenkins can read it.
Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
```

If I create a file /tmp/.ssh/known_hosts and put the agent's hostname and the user's public key in it, it connects ok. But the /tmp is cleaned out after every reboot, and I have to do the procedure again. All I can find as to a possible cause is if JENKINS_HOME was set to /tmp, but it's not; Jenkins is running as:

```
/etc/alternatives/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/netfs/data/jenkins -jar /netfs/data/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/netfs/data/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/netfs/data/jenkins/war --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8080 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20 --httpsPrivateKey=/netfs/data/jenkins/jenkins.key --httpsCertificate=/netfs/data/jenkins/jenkins.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Jenkins reads its home dir location once at start time. If you change it while Jenkins is running, it won't pick up on that.

When I first started the Jenkins service, it was running as a user defined in /etc/passwd. That user had a home dir of /tmp. I edited /etc/passwd so its home dir became /home/. I didn't restart the Jenkins service at that point. Apparently, it detects and stores the location of the home dir of the user it's running as. It doesn't recheck. Which credential I was using was irrelevant.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).